# The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found

Tags: linux, debian, apt, ntc-pocketchip

I have C.H.I.P. and I had to reflash it (Jessie, server (I also had PocketCHIP image which wasn't playing well with my original C.H.I.P, so I went to server image), stable) due to corrupted installation. Now it's a clean installation and I want to install `git`.

I went ahead:

```
root@chip:~# sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package git
```

I tried to update:

```
root@chip:~# sudo apt-get update
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.            
N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?
```

After this error, I tried to install `apt-transport-https`:

```
root@chip:~# sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apt-transport-https
```

I decided to build it manually by downloading the tarball from `https://packages.debian.org/jessie/apt-transport-https`:

```
root@chip:~/tmp/apt-1.0.9.8.5# ./configure 
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh buildlib/config.sub
```

Now I'm literally stuck. It's a clean fresh image, `apt-get` does not allow anything over HTTPS. I'm also unable to install apt-transport-https. Here's my sources:

```
root@chip:~/tmp/apt-1.0.9.8.5# more /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free

deb http://opensource.nextthing.co/chip/debian/repo jessie main
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've found and installed `libcurl3-gnutls_7.38.0-4+deb8u14_armhf.deb` `libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.9.8.5_armhf.deb` and `apt-transport-https_1.0.9.8.5_armhf.deb` manually and I could get it to working. Now HTTPS is working but it still can't find any repos even after update, but that seems to be another question.